# Task fails in Spark with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I am trying to write a simple java program which will read data from Cassandra via Spark. I am doing this at POC level. My code looks like this

```
String keyspace = "newkspace1";
String tablename = "newtable5";
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        conf.setAppName("Cassandra Demo");
        conf.setMaster("spark://ct-0094:7077");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.50.124");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port", "9041");
        conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.rpc.port", "9160");
        PerformerClass app = new PerformerClass(conf);
        app.run();
    } 
private void run() 
    {
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        showResults(sc);
        sc.stop();
    }
 private void showResults(JavaSparkContext sc) 
    {
        CassandraJavaPairRDD<Integer, Integer> rdd1 = javaFunctions(sc)
                .cassandraTable(keyspace, tablename, mapColumnTo(Integer.class), mapColumnTo(Integer.class))
                .select("keyval", "rangefield");


        List<Integer> lst = rdd1.keys().toArray();
        for(Integer l : lst)
        {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
```

When I ran the above code, I got the following exceptions (Stack trace pasted below)

> 15/01/15 19:22:41 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, ct-0094): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
>       [...]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it myself by going through some blogs.

Actually the jar of the program must be included in the program itself like

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
sc.addJar("./target/SparkPOC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar");
```

This solves the problem.
But everytime before running your code, you have to Maven Install (that is create the jar) your code and then run it. I am still looking for the better approach where these steps can be avoided.

Comment: Doesn't seem right, are you able to build this example and run it? https://github.com/rssvihla/spark_commons/blob/master/examples/spark_bulk_operations/src/main/java/pro/foundev/java/AbstractCassandraConnectorClass.java

Comment: actually when i was trying to run my code in IDE, I got above mentioned exception. So I used `sc.addJar()`. But if you want to build the JAR and run it directly on spark cluster, then you don't need sc.addJar(). (this is my understanding.)

Comment: Are you running your job using spark-submit?